# Output unmatched columns when comparing two sql tables

Tags: sql

I need to build a query where I can output only the columns which do not match in two tables A and B (same structure)

For example table A and B both have 10 columns with same 3 primary keys.
(Reason for doing this is to find data entry errors in either table A or B)

For example table A has the values:
A B C 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (this is one row, A B C are the values for primary keys)
Table B has the values 
A B C 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 (this is one row, A B C are the values for primary keys)

As you can see the 10th column has different values (7 in table A, 8 in table B).
The result of the query should be Columns 1,2,3 & 10, along with the values in table B.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How does a query return a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a union query such as:

```sql
SELECT Table2.Key1, Table2.Key2, Table2.Key3, CASE WHEN Table1.Value1 <> Table2.Value1 THEN 'Value1' END AS DifferingFields
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Key1 = Table1.Key1 AND Table2.Key2 = Table1.Key2 AND Table2.Key3 = Table1.Key3
WHERE Table1.Value1 <> Table2.Value1
UNION ALL
SELECT Table2.Key1, Table2.Key2, Table2.Key3, CASE WHEN Table1.Value2 <> Table2.Value2 THEN 'Value2' END
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Key1 = Table1.Key1 AND Table2.Key2 = Table1.Key2 AND Table2.Key3 = Table1.Key3
WHERE Table1.Value2 <> Table2.Value2
UNION ALL
SELECT Table2.Key1, Table2.Key2, Table2.Key3, CASE WHEN Table1.Value3 <> Table2.Value3 THEN 'Value3' END
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Key1 = Table1.Key1 AND Table2.Key2 = Table1.Key2 AND Table2.Key3 = Table1.Key3
WHERE Table1.Value3 <> Table2.Value3
[... add statements for the remaining value fields ...]
```

This will return the values of the 3 key fields, with the names of the fields that are contain differing values.

For Microsoft Access, use:

```sql
SELECT Table2.Key1, Table2.Key2, Table2.Key3, IIF(Table1.Value1 <> Table2.Value1,"Value1","") AS DifferingFields
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Key1 = Table1.Key1 AND Table2.Key2 = Table1.Key2 AND Table2.Key3 = Table1.Key3
WHERE Table1.Value1 <> Table2.Value1
UNION ALL
SELECT Table2.Key1, Table2.Key2, Table2.Key3, IIF(Table1.Value2 <> Table2.Value2, "Value2","")
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Key1 = Table1.Key1 AND Table2.Key2 = Table1.Key2 AND Table2.Key3 = Table1.Key3
WHERE Table1.Value2 <> Table2.Value2
UNION ALL
SELECT Table2.Key1, Table2.Key2, Table2.Key3, IIF(Table1.Value3 <> Table2.Value3, "Value3","")
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Key1 = Table1.Key1 AND Table2.Key2 = Table1.Key2 AND Table2.Key3 = Table1.Key3
WHERE Table1.Value3 <> Table2.Value3
```

If you consider the following data:

Table1:

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 6 | 10 |

Table2:

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 11 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 11 |

You get these results:

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | DifferingFields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | Value2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | Value3 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | Value3 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | Value3 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | Value3 |

Comment: Thanks Max, I will try the above suggestion!

Comment: Then transpose the differing fields column to get the value2 & value3 for 1 2 6 in the same row? like this: 1 2 6 value2 value3

Comment: I have 68 columns I need to compare, so it gives me a "Query is too complex" error message. The solution seems to break up the query in to multiple queries, could there be any other reason or solution instead of breaking the query in to multiple queries? I spent almost half an hour building this query!

Comment: Actually I split the query in to two queries and it worked! The only thing left is to get the results in a horizontal fashion.I will try to use cross tab query and see...Thanks Max!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very simple to return the rows that differ:

```
select t1.A, t1.B, t1.C
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C
where t1.C1 != t2.C1 or t1.C2 != t2.C2 -- and so on for the remaining columns
```

This will return the primary key of the rows that are different. If you really need to name of the column they are different at, it will become much more complex as you need to return the same number of columns for each row. You can't have a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Yes, this is what I did. But I need the exact column where the rows differ. Is there a way I can just mark the columns where the rows differ, this way I don't need dynamic number of columns generated.

Comment: I can't help you with that, sorry